# How to automatically post to Facebook

Tags: facebook

Please could you help. I have created a website that allows people to upload listings of items they are selling. I want to know how to add the feature where when someone creates a listing, it automatically posts on the user's FB page, with a link to the listing on our website. Is this possible? Would the user have to log into our website using their FB account for this to happen? Thanks everyone for your help.

Martin

Comment: Of course they would have to login to your app and grant it permission first. And publishing “automatically” is not really allowed; under normal cirumstances, the user should actively confirm every single post that is made. Plus, the message part of any post/share (at least to a user timeline) has to be typed in by the user, your app is not allowed to prefill it with content from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Facebook App and use [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_post_links) with publish_actions permissions to do that. Note that the facebook rules prohibit sending fully automated messages that the user has no control, your user must have the ability to edit the message before sending